# Is there a shortcut for opening the dev tools Network tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know if there is a shortcut for opening the Network tab in dev tools in Chrome. I know there is a shortcut for opening dev tools and the Console tab, but not for opening the Network tab.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought if you press `f12` and select network tab and close, the next time you press `f12` it opens there by default. I also drag network tab to the far most left tab too so maybe that is why I see that always open network tab when I press `f12`. From there you can press `ctrl+r` to record network too.

Comment: Yes, but if I had any other tab open before and reopen the dev tools window I want to be able to open it with the Network tab shown directly with a shortcut.

Comment: The Chrome DevTools docs only mention shortcuts for opening the last pane, the console, or the elements view. There's probably not a shortcut for network. The closest thing would be enabling the ctrl+# shortcuts to switch panes, or pressing ctrl+shift+p in the dev tools and typing "Network".

Comment: @LayneBernardo the ctrl+shift+p shortcut is really handy. Will use that. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows:

1.

1.1) go to DevTools: <kbd>F12</kbd>

1.2) open the Command Menu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

1.3) type: network, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

2.

2.1 If the Network was the panel you used last, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: This is very useful. It can be used to access any tab by only using the keyboard.

Comment: Pretty much the same for Mac, most Mac keyboards have F12 as the volume up control though, so typically it's going to be Fn+F12, or you can also Cmd+Opt+J. Then to open the command menu, it's Cmd+Shift+P. I typically just use the Opt+Cmd+I shortcut to open the last tab I used in developer tools, usually Network.

Answer (score 5):

For Mac you can use this :

Option + ⌘ + I

Comment: This is a useful shortcut. It doesn't necessarily open the Network tab, it opens the last used tab. So it doesn't exactly answer the question, but I *mostly* use the Network tab so it works well enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: The letter is `i`, not the `L` lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you can use:

Ctrl + Shift + I

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The other answer seems to cover better the Windows case.